# Recover C++ class declaration from ELF binary generated by GCC 2.95

Tags: c++, gcc, reverse-engineering

Is it possible (that is, could be easily accomplished with commodity tools) to reconstruct a C++ class declaration from a *.so* file (non-debug, non-x86) — to the point that member functions could be called successfully as if the original *.h* file was available for that class?

For example, by trial and error I found that this code works when 64K are allocated for instance-local storage. Allocating 1K or 8K leads to SEGFAULT, although I never saw offsets higher than 0x0650 in disassembly and it is highly unlikely that this class actually stores much data by itself.

```
class TS57 {
private:
    char abLocalStorage[65536]; // Large enough to fit all possible instance data.
public:
    TS57(int iSomething);
    ~TS57(void);
    int SaveAsMap(long (*)(long, long, long, long, long), char const*, char const*, char const*);
};
```

And what if I needed more complex classes and usage scenarios? What if allocating 64K per instance would be too wasteful? Are there simple tools (like `nm` or `objdump`) that may give insight on a *.so* library's type information? I found some papers on *SecondWrite* — an “executable analysis and rewriting framework” which does “recovery of object oriented features from C++ binaries”, — but, despite several references in newsgroups, could not even conclude whether this is a production-ready software, or just a proof of concept, or a private tool not for general use.

FYI. I am asking this totally out of curiosity. I already found a C-style wrapper for that function that not only instantiates the object and calls its method, but also conveniently does additional housekeeping. Moreover, I am not enthusiastic to write for G++ 2.95 — as this was the version that library was compiled by, and I could not find a switch to get the same name mangling scheme in my usual G++ 3.3. Therefore, I am not interested in workarounds: I wonder whether a direct solution exists — in case it is needed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no, a machine can't do that".

The longer answer is still roughly the same, but I'll try to explain why:

Some information about functions would be available from `nm libmystuff.so|c++filt`, which will demangle the names. But that will only show functions that have a public name, and it will most likely still be a bit ambiguous as to what the data-types actually mean.

During compilation, a lot of "semantical information"[1] is lost. Functions are inlined, loops are transforme [loops made with `for`, `do-while` and `while`, even `goto` in some cases, are made to look almost identical), conditions are compiled out or re-arranged, variable names are lost, much of the type information and enum-names are completely lost, etc. Private and public fields of classes would be lost.

Compiler will also do "clever" transformations on the code to replace complex instructions with less complex ones (`int x; ...  x = x * 5` may become `lea eax, [eax*4 + eax]` or similar) [this one is pretty simple - try figuring out "backwards" how the compiler solved a `populationcount` (number of bits set in a binary number) or `cosine` when it has been inlined...]

A human, that knows what the code is MEANT to do, and good knowledge of the machine code of the target processor, MAY be able to reverse engineer the code and break out functions that have been inlined. But it's still hard to tell the difference between:

```
void Foo::func()
{
    this->x++;
}
```

and

```
void func(Foo* p)
{
    p->x++;
}
```

These two functions should become exactly identical machine-code, and if the function does not have a name in the symbol table, there is no way to tell which it is.

[1] Information about the "meaning" of the code.

Comment: Good point, but you are overly focused on methods, while my question was mostly about data. Recovering function signature is usually not a problem, as name mangling preserves it; even if we are after a C-style function, we can [most of the time] easily analyze the disassembly (especially on platforms that have registers exactly for that task). This, however, does not tell us how much memory each instance allocates statically — how big that fake `abLocalStorage` should be. If no information is saved about that, — then, well, trial and error is all we are left with.

Comment: As for the inlined functions and other optimizations, — why would I want to call an inlined function, if I do not even know that it existed in source code? Why would I care about what happens inside a called function? If it is exportable, then it *was* intended for external use, and the callee should not be worried about its implementation. The only thing that matters is ABI, including data allocation strategy (field layout and alignment).

Comment: All depends on what you actually want to achieve. With enough analysis of the machine code, static allocation size should be plausible to determine. But it's of course not necessarily EASY, depending on how the code was originally written, it can be pretty open-ended [there may be loops that just run to the number of elements added, and you don't know the upper limit, for example]. And of course, it largely depends on what the intent of the reverse engineering is. All cases I've worked on has involved "being able to change things".